# Error 1064 when using SQL with INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to use 'INSERT INTO ... SELECT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE feature' but I'm in trouble now.

I want to insert data to 'fruitProperty' table.

My query is as below:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SET @myVal1 := "";
SET @myVal2 := 0;
SET @myVal3 := 0;
SET @myVal4 := 0;
SET @myVal5 := 0;

SELECT masterIndex INTO @myVal1 FROM fruitMaster WHERE masterName = 'apple';
SELECT masterIndex INTO @myVal2 FROM fruitMaster WHERE masterName = 'banana';
SELECT masterIndex INTO @myVal3 FROM fruitMaster WHERE masterName = 'mango';
SELECT masterIndex INTO @myVal4 FROM fruitMaster WHERE masterName = 'melon';
SELECT masterIndex INTO @myVal5 FROM fruitMaster WHERE masterName = 'grape';

INSERT
INTO    fruitProperty
        (fruitID, masterIndex, cpValue)
SELECT  A1.fruitID, A2.masterIndex, A2.cpValue
FROM    (   
           SELECT   A.fruitID
           FROM     fruit A
                    JOIN fruitProperty B ON A.fruitID = B.fruitID
           WHERE    B.masterIndex = @myVal1 AND B.cpValue = 1
        ) A1
        CROSS JOIN
        (
           SELECT @myVal2 AS masterIndex, 1 AS cpValue
           UNION
           SELECT @myVal3, 1
           UNION
           SELECT @myVal4, 1
           UNION
           SELECT @myVal5, 1
       ) A2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cpValue = cpValue + 1;

ROLLBACK;
```

I met an error code.

> error code: 1064 
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'KEY UPDATE cpValue = 1' at line 21

What's wrong with my query? I really don't know..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get a problem if you use an explicit `join`:

```
INSERT INTO fruitProperty (fruitID, masterIndex, cpValue)
SELECT f.fruitID, A2.masterIndex, A2.cpValue
FROM (SELECT f.fruitID
      FROM fruit f JOIN
           fruitProperty fp
            ON f.fruitID = fp.fruitID
      WHERE f.masterIndex = @myVal1 AND fp.cpValue = 1
     ) f JOIN
     (SELECT @myVal2 AS masterIndex, 1 AS cpValue
      UNION ALL
      SELECT @myVal3, 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT @myVal4, 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT @myVal5, 1
     ) A2
     ON 1=1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cpValue = VALUES(cpValue) + 1;
```

I suspect the problem is a parsing problem, because MySQL/MariaDB supports the `ON` clause for `CROSS JOIN` (yuck!!!).  But the `ON` keyword gets confused.

Comment: I've changed the query like you suggested and I got another error. It says 'Error code: 1052 Column 'cpValue' in field list is ambiguous'. And what is the meaning of 'ON 1=1'????

Comment: @passion053 . . . Probably you want to increment the value in place, so use `VALUES()`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could simplify it without using that CROSS JOIN.

In MySql a CROSS JOIN is sadly just a synonym for INNER JOIN.

But you don't want that last `ON` keyword to be confused as part of the JOIN.

**Sample data**

> ```
> create table fruitMaster (masterIndex int primary key, masterName varchar(30));
>
> insert into fruitMaster (masterIndex, masterName) values 
> (1, 'apple'),(2, 'banana'),(3, 'mango'),(4, 'melon'),(5, 'grape'), (6, 'prune');
>
> create table fruit (fruitID int primary key, fruitName varchar(30));
>
> insert into fruit (fruitID, fruitName) values 
> (10,'jonagold'),(20,'straight banana'),(40,'big melons');
>
> create table fruitProperty (
>  fruitID int, masterIndex int, cpValue int,
>  primary key (fruitID, masterIndex));
>
> insert into fruitProperty (fruitID, masterIndex, cpValue) values
> (10, 1, 1),(10, 2, 1),(10, 6, 1),
> (20, 2, 1),(30, 3, 1),(40, 4, 1);
> ```

**Insert query**

> ```
> INSERT INTO fruitProperty (fruitID, masterIndex, cpValue)
> SELECT F.fruitID, FM2.masterIndex, 1 AS cpValue
> FROM fruit F
> JOIN fruitProperty FP ON (FP.fruitID = F.fruitID AND FP.cpValue = 1)
> JOIN fruitMaster FM1 ON (FM1.masterIndex = FP.masterIndex AND FM1.masterName = 'apple')
> JOIN fruitMaster FM2 ON FM2.masterName IN ('banana', 'mango', 'melon', 'grape')
> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cpValue = 2;
> ```

**Result:**

> ```
> SELECT * FROM fruitProperty;
> ```
>
> ```
> fruitID | masterIndex | cpValue
> ------: | ----------: | ------:
>      10 |           1 |       1
>      10 |           2 |       2
>      10 |           3 |       1
>      10 |           4 |       1
>      10 |           5 |       1
>      10 |           6 |       1
>      20 |           2 |       1
>      30 |           3 |       1
>      40 |           4 |       1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=930a961b1a0f232d730df50ef807f216)*

Comment: "In MySql a CROSS JOIN is sadly just a synonym for INNER JOIN. But you don't want that last ON keyword to be confused as part of the JOIN." You gave us a inspiration. I'm really thank to you. Thank you very much.